# In jsp page Confirm only appear on first row form button click. On second row form submit it does not appear and my ajax call is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have developed spring boot web application, on front end I have JSP pages.
I am displaying list of user in table and there are corresponding action(form for each action) like update, reset, delete etc in my each row. On Delete action I am first displaying confirm message. If user press Ok I am making Ajax get call to Controller which delete user from database and return status 0 or 1. I have notice that on first record it show confirm and on OK it send the call and proper response is return back. When I click on second record delete button it does not show confirm message and submit the form which return error 405 Get Method not supported. I have also observe no other record is work as per behavior.

My JSP code is as below

I have tried different way to show confirm message like onclick I have tried to execute it but same is result.
I have remove all other js/css libraries and only j query on my page but it produce same output. I have also tried to create a simple page and simulate same behavior it also show same.

```
<div id="disabledContent" class="container border rounded bg-light"
   style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <form method="post" action="/createUserDetails">
      <button type="submit" value="Add User"
         class="btn btn-success btn-lg">+</button>
   </form>
   <table class="table table-light">
      <thead class="thead-light">
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th colspan="6" scope="col">Actions</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="item">
            <tr>
               <td>${item.firstName}</td>
               <td>${item.lastName}</td>
               <td>
                  <form method="post" action="/assignUserLicense">
                     <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${item.id}">
                     <input type="hidden" name="customerUniqueId"
                        value="${customerUniqueId}">
                     <button type="submit" value="Assign License"
                        class="btn btn-warning">Assign License</button>
                  </form>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <form method="post" action="/unassignUserLicense">
                     <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${item.id}">
                     <input type="hidden" name="customerUniqueId"
                        value="${customerUniqueId}">
                     <button type="submit" value="UnAssign License"
                        class="btn btn-warning">Unassign License</button>
                  </form>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <form method="post" action="/modifyUserDetails"
                     id="modifyUserDetailsForm">
                     <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId"
                        value="${item.id}"> <input type="hidden"
                        name="customerUniqueId" id="customerUniqueId"
                        value="${customerUniqueId}"> <input type="hidden"
                        name="displayName" id="displayName"
                        value="${item.displayName}"> <input type="hidden"
                        name="userPrincipalName" id="userPrincipalName"
                        value="${item.userPrincipalName}"> <input
                        type="hidden" name="firstName" id="firstName"
                        value="${item.firstName}"> <input type="hidden"
                        name="lastName" id="lastName" value="${item.lastName}">
                     <button type="submit" value="Modify User"
                        class="btn btn-warning">Modify User</button>
                  </form>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <form method="post" action="/resetUserUserDetails">
                     <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${item.id}">
                     <input type="hidden" name="customerUniqueId"
                        value="${customerUniqueId}">
                     <button type="submit" value="Get User"
                        class="btn btn-warning">Reset Password</button>
                  </form>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <form id="myDeleteFrom">
                     <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="${item.id}">
                     <input type="hidden" name="customerUniqueId"
                        value="${customerUniqueId}">
                     <button type="submit" value="Get User"
                        class="btn btn-warning">Delete User</button>
                  </form>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

my javascript code
$(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {

```
                    $("#myDeleteFrom")
                            .submit(
                                    function() {
                                        var confirmResponse = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user");

                                        if (confirmResponse) {
                                            //Ajax get call 
                                        } else {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                });
```

I am expecting it should work on any row delete form submit button click.

Comment: You have a button with id = 'myDeleteFrom' in every row. IDs are meant to be unique and cannot be the same for multiple elements. Assign a class to the button and refer by using class for each button to work independently.

Comment: there is no `action` attribute in form tag of delete

Comment: @KamleshBhurke I have id on my form field when I click on the button my form is processed by jquery in above javascript code.

Comment: @NawedKhan Well I am suspecting the same. I have removed jquery and tried to perform same with javascript onclick i have called some function here i am able to display confirm message but one thing I have notice is that my userId remain same. However I have created another page and from here I have sent post request and view the data on the other page there it show right user id for every record. But when I try to perform this action via javascript/jquery it return same id for every record.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JQuery or Javascript. The jsp is creating rows and every form has the same id. Change <form id="myDeleteFrom"> to <form class="myDeleteFrom">. And then change $("#myDeleteFrom") to $(".myDeleteFrom")

Comment: Well now confirm is working on each click but problem now is for userId it value remain same it value is not getting change. What to do now.

Comment: when you are using `submit()` function the page gets reloaded on submit and the ajax response is not there and so you are not getting return value

Comment: Hi Kamlesh my first problem is solved as per Nawed Khan feedback. Now only problem is to return every row record user id value where now it is return same user id value on every delete button click.

Comment: @NawedKhan I have assign Id to each row, since my user id is unique from following code i can get the value $(this).closest('tr').attr('id') it give me my user id. Can you advise is it safe to do or is there any side affect of this. I know this is temporarily work around i have done in order to make the things work and i can test my application.

Comment: Please update the code in your question. I do not see any tr that has an id assigned to it or where in your code are you trying to read the userid. Doesn't the mydeleteForm already have userid and customerUniqueId? Give these input fields a class name and you can read value with $(this).find('.useridclassname').val()

Comment: I have added <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="item"> <tr id="${item.id}"> but your provided solution also work for me and i guess it is appropriate to use instead of use id on tr. Now my final point is i want to remove this row once ajax call is successfully executed. should I use class on tr and then remove it.

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').remove() should be sufficient.

Comment: @NawedKhan I have applied this it work if i execute it before ajax call. When on success response I try to execute this remove code it does not work.

Comment: @NawedKhan I have applied this it work if i execute it before ajax call. When on success response I try to execute this remove code, it does not work. It also does not remove row even i place it after ajax call execution block.

Comment: Hi I manage to solve this in following way before ajax call I have var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); and on ajax success I have executed following code $tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
                            $tr.remove();                    
                        }); and it has removed the row. Thanks for your support.